# getItemSummariesWithoutItemData returns every account several times

Tags: yodlee

Using [getItemSummariesWithoutItemData](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummariesWithoutItemData) API endpoint + [FastLink](https://developer.yodlee.com/Account_Verification/FastLink_Integration_Guide_For_IAV).

If I open frame and log in once - getItemSummariesWithoutItemData returns proper result.
But when I open FastLink frame again (for another activity) and user logs into the same bank **getItemSummariesWithoutItemData** returns the same record twice.

How can I remove duplicates from **getItemSummariesWithoutItemData** response?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally we do not return duplicates.

You can distinguish between the accounts which you have added, by checking  the**memSiteAccId** (in the API response) as this is unique for a site account.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik